# how to draw curve graph in c#

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

i have some count with names like

```
Tennis  10

Cricket  12

Boxing   15

FootBall 20

Golf     14
```

i have drawn graph statically but i want to draw it has dynamic when ever values change graph should change

Comment: 1. Why would you want a curve for this? 2. What have you tried so far and what exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: so far im new to this i have drawn the graph in excel and took image of that using paint this image i have shown statically but i want it dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's very urgent, you could use [Google Chart](http://code.google.com/apis/charttools/index.html): You download the image or show it directly in a HTML container. You simply have to update the URL to generate a new graph.

If you mean animated graph it'll take longer. You may use WPF Dynamic Data Display or a Flash is you have simple constraints and want a lot of visual effects.

Just throwing ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [WPF Dynamic Data Display](http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/) library.

I've used it in the past to build live dashboards.  The samples included should contain everything you need to get up and running.